# ssh on unix socket

Tags: ssh, unix-sockets

I have some old unix running as vm on VirtualBox server
those vm had the serial ports simulated by unix socket
for example: an old AT&T 2.1 SVr4 has socket on /tmp/att1
to connect i did

```
minicom -D  unix#/tmp/att1
```

on server.

I heard somewhere ssh can connect to unix sockets.
How to do?

I have tried

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:5500 EXEC:'ssh user@server "socat STDIO UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/att1"'
```

Then

```
ssh server -p 5500
```

But give me error

```
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 192.168.0.2: message authentication code incorrect
```

Also tried

```
ssh -R/tmp/att1:/tmp/att1  -R127.0.0.1:1233:/tmp/att1
```

But failed with remote port failed error.

Suggestions?

Comment: no, you can't connect using `ssh` to UNIX domain socket simulating serial console. You would need SSHD server on the other side and your machines probably pre-dates the whole protocol. You got it probably confused by the forwarding of UNIX domain socket.

Comment: Yes right,the only possibility to get ssh via serial is a server wich run sshd and translate/connect  tcp-connection to serial connection,wich the client see transparent as a normal tcp connection. A hw thing like this exist,is called "terminal server". A sw solution will be good imho.If you want to get your comment voted,add it as answer,i will close question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't connect using `ssh` to UNIX domain socket simulating serial console. You would need SSHD server on the other side and your machines probably pre-dates the whole SSH protocol.

You got this probably confused by the forwarding of UNIX domain socket, which is possible as port-forwarding.

Comment: Could you run sshd on the other side of the serial line in inetd mode somehow?  I can't think of any reason why that wouldn't work aside from not being certain how to attach it to the virtual serial port...